# AIR iOs app hides the battery and other status bars on iPhone?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm creating an AIR iOs app using flash cs6 AS3.

The issue that I have at the moment is that when I publish the app from adobe flash cs6 and install the app on my iPhone, it will hide all the status stuff (battery, signal etc) that is displayed on the top of the iPhone screen!

basically when I open the app on my iPhone, it will load as it should and it works fine BUT the problem is that no status bar (battery, signal, network etc etc) is shown at the top of the iPhone's screen while the APP is open!

is there any special code that i need to put it my AIR application for that?

any advise would be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: set fullscreen to false in your app description xml.

Comment: As of iOS 7, apps use the full height of the screen and actually appear under the status bar. The icons and text in that bar are white by default, so if your app is also white at the top of the screen, the status bar will seem to be invisible. Try changing your background to a dark color (or light if it is already dark). If that is the issue, there are a few options for getting around this more permanently.

Comment: @BotMaster, i just looked in my xml file and the full screen is set to true so I think you are right mate.... I haven't tested it yet as I have no access to an iPhone. I will test it with full screen false and will update this post. you might want to add an answer an I will accept it as I will give it 99% that you are correct .:)

Comment: @JoshJanusch, thanks buddy.. I will try your solution as well but I think BotMaster's comment is more likely to be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

In you application descriptor file, having option to enable fullscreen or not. If you set

```
<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
```

Your application going take the entire screen height and width. **Here, you could not able to see the status bar.**

```
<fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
```

Your application going to take the normal mode, here you can see the status bar.

**This supports both android and ios.**